# Custom rendering with around filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  around_filter :custom_render
  def index
    # a lot of logic here with long external requests
  end

  def custom_render
    # some complicated logic like render(file: '/templates/category_type/action_name.html.haml')
  end
end
```

Does `custom_render` will always be after logic in index action , and wait until logic in index action will end?

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not always run after the `index` method.

It will run *before* and/or *after* that method, because you use a [`around_filter`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#after-filters-and-around-filters). It depends on how you implement the `custom_render` method (aka where you put the `yield`):

```
def custom_render
  # some code that will run before the action

  yield # here your index action runs

  # some code that will run after the action
end
```

Form the docs:

> "Around" filters are responsible for running their associated actions by yielding, similar to how Rack middlewares work.

That said: The response is already rendered when the method returns to the around filter, therefore you cannot change the rendering behavior in an after or around filter.

Comment: Thank's for answer, but if I add render logic after yield, it will not run, how to fix it ? What you think?

Comment: @rs41 I updated me answer to address your question. Can you please describe what you try to achieve? There might be other options, but you need to describe what you aim for, please elaborate on what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I want to have some logic in controller and after this logic in the end render specific file. ( Arguments in ```render``` will be different) Is there a simple solution for this ?

Comment: I still don't get the problem you are trying to solve. Why not just a simple rendering in the action, when there different arguments anyway? Or a simple helper method? Or a dynamic `layout` filter?

Comment: I have 2-5 controllers which must use this custom render method, for now i moved this render method to around_filter and it seems work, but I am not sure about it )